# What does the word "deterministic" mean in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am studying for a programming exam and one of the words I need to know is deterministic as it applies to python.

Comment: ... as it applies to Python? I was unaware that us Python folks take that standard term and bend it to mean something different.

Answer (score 5):

A program is deterministic if you get the same result and behavior every time you run it. The term is not particular for Python.

Comment: thanks!! I wasn't sure if it is particular to python or not. My programming class is mainly python though.

Comment: I'm curious if you or anyone else knows of a non-deterministic programming language? It's hard to imagine it being very useful -- as in you never know what it's going to do...seems like debugging would be a real nightmare.

Comment: The term deterministic or non-deterministic (stochastic) can be applied to algorithms, and stochastic algorithms are quite common, e,g, genetic algorithm.

Comment: Anything for quantum computers is non-deterministic I think, but still sounds rather useful.

Comment: @martineau: On the contrary, pretty much all Python programs are indeterministic. If they involve any I/O, external calls (eg. checking the time), randomness, etc. there goes determinism. Which is why coding in a language like Haskell where by default functions are pure is a pain.

Answer (score -2):

There is a reference to this [in the Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.2p1/lib/Deterministic_Profiling.html), the first result returned by a search on Google.

> Deterministic profiling is meant to reflect the fact that all function call, function return, and exception events are monitored, and precise timings are made for the intervals between these events (during which time the user's code is executing). In contrast, statistical profiling (which is not done by this module) randomly samples the effective instruction pointer, and deduces where time is being spent. The latter technique traditionally involves less overhead (as the code does not need to be instrumented), but provides only relative indications of where time is being spent.
>
> In Python, since there is an interpreter active during execution, the
>   presence of instrumented code is not required to do deterministic
>   profiling. Python automatically provides a hook (optional callback)
>   for each event. In addition, the interpreted nature of Python tends to
>   add so much overhead to execution, that deterministic profiling tends
>   to only add small processing overhead in typical applications. The
>   result is that deterministic profiling is not that expensive, yet
>   provides extensive run time statistics about the execution of a Python
>   program.
>
> Call count statistics can be used to identify bugs in code (surprising
>   counts), and to identify possible inline-expansion points (high call
>   counts). Internal time statistics can be used to identify ``hot
>   loops'' that should be carefully optimized. Cumulative time statistics
>   should be used to identify high level errors in the selection of
>   algorithms. Note that the unusual handling of cumulative times in this
>   profiler allows statistics for recursive implementations of algorithms
>   to be directly compared to iterative implementations.

Comment: -1 What you quote is specifically about a very specific term (deterministic profiling) that happens to include "deterministic" (compatible with the general meaning, but specialized so much that you can't simply derive a general definition from this).

Comment: I was thinking that if this person has an exam on Python specifically, it would be relevant. However it wouldn't be an answer that would be helpful for everyone.

Comment: No, it's not helpful for someone using Python specifically. It's helpful for someone interested in profiling (in any language). I doubt OP's exam is about profiling. It's much more likely to be a CS topic where determinism (in the sense of the other answer) of programs/algorithms is relevant.

Comment: -1 because I think it might actually be misleading to the OP...